# Would it be possible for NATO to intercept russian cruise missiles over the Ukraine from NATO airspace, and avoid becoming a party of the war?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, nato, rules-of-war

In media reports and discussions, the impossibility of a no-fly zone was discussed since the current (2022) war in Ukraine started.

Basically, a no-fly zone would entail NATO jets shooting down russian jets, which is something leaders on all sides (hopefully) are working hard to avoid.

However, what if NATO jets stay in NATO airspace and shoot down russian cruise missiles which happen to come into range, e.g., by being on their way to the western Ukraine (Lwiw comes to mind)?

In such a case, NATO would attack only russian military hardware, however, there would be no russian casualties diretly attributable to NATO.

Comment: VTC because this question is not about politics. From a purely logistics aspect of it, launching missiles from your planes, on your territory, that hit targets on a neighbour country means your country is directly intervening in the war, and that would constitute an escalation over simply sending weapons to Ukraine. And while in theory hitting just cruise missiles would be less of a hazard than shooting down jets, remember that mistaking a passenger airline jet for a military aircraft has already happened before. Mistaking a missile for a drone, or a drone for an hellicopter would be too easy.

Comment: I think this question is about politics, especially where to draw the line between giving material support and being an active participant in a war. Right now, NATO hands over systems to the Ukraine, and Ukrainians are pushing the button on Ukrainian soild. However, NATO providing protection agains cruise missiles while not entering the Ukraine would be somewhere in-between "simply providing arms" and "entering the war".

Comment: What do you mean by 'possible'? If you're asking if NATO equipment has the capability to shoot down missiles, that's not a politics question. If you're asking if they can do it without the same ramifications as explicitly entering the war, then that'd be mostly based on speculation.

Comment: I am asking on what would be the consequences of actually doing it. I have no doubt that the equipment is capable of doing it.

Comment: Maybe you could ask if anyone in NATO or Russia has discussed this as an option? Otherwise it's asking for how people would behave in a hypothetical situation that none of the relevant parties may be thinking about.

Comment: It's definitely relevant as to whether it's physically possible to do it reliably. It's one thing for Ukraine to fire anti-missile missiles that occasionally miss and hit civilians in Ukraine or its neighbors, but it's different for the US to do the same. If US missiles inadvertently hit Belarus or Russia, that could cause a serious escalation. This is a complex question but it definitely involves a mix of skills, including predicting the future.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  Not sure why this wouldn't be a rules-of-war question (as it is already tagged).  It seems pretty much within the scope of the site by all the measures.

Comment: What is the actual question here? The capability of military equipment isn't on topic here and that is what the question seems to be about. If you are asking how Russia would respond this hypothetical situation we are not able to guess how they would react.

Comment: I believe that technically this would be an act of war. So it would come down to *which* acts of war Russia is going to ignore, which is rather hard to guess.